# design Postgres database schema for arbitrary JSON attribute queries

Tags: postgresql, json, jsonb

In my Postgres database, I have got lots of data (a million rows) and the schema looks like this:

```
create table test_tb (
  id int,
  tags jsonb
);
```

A few queries to be performed on this dataset are:

1.

```
select id, tags ->> 'tag_1' as tag_1
from test_tb
where tags ->> 'tag_1'= 'val_1'
```

2. 

```
select id, tags ->> 'tag_2' as tag_2
from test_tb
```

3. 

```
select id, tags ->> 'tag_1'
from test_tb
WHERE (tags ->> 'tag_1'='dv_0'
  AND tags ->> 'tag_3'='dv_15')
  AND (tags ->> 'tag_15'='dv_22' OR tags ->> 'tag_5'='dv_6')
   OR (tags ->> 'tag_12'='dv_9');
```

Now the tags in each tuple are completely arbitrary, one tag might be appearing in only one tuple while another in hundreds of them, the number of tags in each tuple is around 20 - 30.

I tried storing tags in a `jsonb` column and put GIN indexing on that column but it didn't optimize my queries. Please suggest some alternate schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to rewrite the queries so that they can use the GIN index. FOr the first query, that would be:

```
SELECT id, tags ->> 'tag_1' as tag_1
FROM test_tb
WHERE tags @> '{ "tag_1": "val_1" }';
```

For the second query, no index can help, since there is no `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clause.

The third query is tricky, because it contains `OR`, but since the result set contains the primary key, you can rewrite it to use the index:

```
   SELECT id, tags ->> 'tag_1'
   FROM test_tb
   WHERE tags @> '{ "tag_1": "dv_0", "tag_3": "dv_15", "tag_15": "dv_22" }'
UNION
   SELECT id, tags ->> 'tag_1'
   FROM test_tb
   WHERE tags @> '{ "tag_1": "dv_0", "tag_3": "dv_15", "tag_5": "dv_6" }'
UNION
   SELECT id, tags ->> 'tag_1'
   FROM test_tb
   WHERE tags @> '{ "tag_12": "dv_9" }';
```

Here, `UNION` is used instead of the `OR`. The query becomes longer, but each of the subqueries can use the index.

Comment: Taking into account ```WHERE ...```, you can rewrite ```SELECT id, tags ->> 'tag_1' as tag_1 ...``` as ```SELECT id, "val_1" as tag_1 ...```.

Comment: @Akina I don't understand. Where does column `val_1` come from?

Comment: WHERE condition provides only this value in the output, and all returned rows will contain it, so what is the reason to extract it again?

Comment: @Akina How does a `WHERE` condition output something? Sorry for being dense...

Comment: There is a lot of rows in the table. They may does not contain tag 'tag_1', they may contain it with the value "val_1", they may contain it with another value. You apply `WHERE tags @> '{ "tag_1": "val_1" }'` (OP applies `where tags ->> 'tag_1'= 'val_1'`). Only rows which contain it with the value "val_1" will be selected. All returned rows will contain "val_1". Replacing the expression with the literal will give absolutely the same output, but less work to the server.

Comment: @Akina Got you. Thanks for your patience.